# Удаление элемента из TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Подскажите как сделать удаление **выделенного** элемента из TreeView? (находящегося не на самом верхнем уровне)

*Как я понимаю - нужно каким то образом получить родителя элемента?*

XAML для TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="PrjTreeViev">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elems}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Привязывается к:

```
ObservableCollection<TreeElem> tree_contents; //элементы TreeView для отображения
PrjTreeViev.ItemsSource = tree_contents;

...

public class TreeElem //класс с списком для отображения
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TreeElem> Elems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Что должно произойти чтобы элемент нужно будет удалить?

Comment: Обычное решение — заполнение TreeView через привязку к коллекции VM-элементов. При этом для удаления элемента нужно просто удалить его из коллекции.

Comment: @VladD, А как понять из какой именно коллекции нужно удалять элемент? Ведь у каждого элемента может быть своя коллекция дочерних элементов. Просто перебирать все?

Comment: Ну, у вас есть сам элемент. Пусть в элементе, например, хранится ссылка на родительский элемент. Тогда удалять нужно из родительского элемента.

Comment: Да я хотел так сделать.
НО разве вот такой код будет работать правильно?
Получается мы должны внуторь дочерних элементов ТекущегоЭлемента добавлять ссылку на СамогоСебя?

Answer (score 1):

Сделаю пример с использованием MVVM паттерна Catel.

> XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="PrjTreeViev" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemTreeView}" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewSource, IsAsync=True}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elems}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Теперь перейдем к коду ViewModel

> C#

```
/// <summary>
///     Регистрируем TreeViewSourceProperty
/// </summary>
public static readonly PropertyData TreeViewSourceProperty = RegisterProperty("TreeViewSource", typeof(List<TreeElem>));

/// <summary>
///     Установка, получение значений из TreeViewSource
/// </summary>
public List<TreeElem> TreeViewSource
{
    get { return GetValue<List<TreeElem>>(TreeViewSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TreeViewSourceProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
///     Регистрируем SelectedItemTreeViewProperty
/// </summary>
public static readonly PropertyData SelectedItemTreeViewProperty = RegisterProperty("SelectedItemTreeView", typeof(TreeElem));

/// <summary>
///     Установка, получение значений из SelectedItemTreeView
/// </summary>
public TreeElem SelectedItemTreeView
{
    get { return GetValue<TreeElem>(SelectedItemTreeViewProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemTreeViewProperty, value); }
}

public class TreeElem //класс с списком для отображения
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TreeElem> Elems { get; set; }
}
```

Так же сделаем команду для для удаления, которая будет недоступна если не выделен элемент.

```
public ICatelCommand DeletSelectedNode => new TaskCommand<TreeElem>(node => Task.Run(() => 
{
    if(MessageBox.Show($"Уверены что хотите удалить данный элмент {node.Name}?", "Подтвердите действие", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Information) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        TreeViewSource.Remove(node); /// Удаляем, если пользователь согласился
}), node => SelectedItemTreeView != null); /// Команда не будет доступна если не выбран элемент в TreeView
```

После всех этих операция создаем кнопку, или контекстное меню, в которых создаем биндинг на нашу команду.

> XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeletSeletedNode}" CommandParametr="{Binding ElementName=PrjTreeViev, Path=SelectedItem}", Content="Удалить элемент">
```

Comment: Где-то могут быть ошибки так как все писалось от руки, без каких либо редакторов.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте свойство

```
public TreeElem SelectedTreeElem { get; set; }
```

привяжите его

```
<TreeView x:Name="PrjTreeViev" ItemsSource="{Binding tree_contents}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreeElem}">
```

Тогда выбранный элемент можно удалить так

```
//тут прежде надо на null проверить SelectedTreeElem
tree_contents.Remove(SelectedTreeElem);
SelectedTreeElem = null;
```